# Antlr4 define a operator which can be Unary or Binary

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

I am in the process of creating a Antlr4 grammar for a language where the logical operator `NOT` and the operators Plus and Minus can be unary or binary operators.

How should I define the operators in Antlr4 grammar so that the parser can differentiate between them ?

Example:

- NOT 1 is 0   (Unary Operator)
- 1 NOT 1 is 0 (Binary Operator)

Here is a small part of my Antlr4 Parser:

```
expr: expr ('%') expr               #Modulo 
| expr op=('*'|'/') expr            #MulDiv
| expr op=('+'|'-') expr            #AddSub                         
| NOT expr                          #NegOp
```

Here is a small part of my Antlr4 Lexer:

```
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
NOT : ([nN][oO][tT]|[~]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a operator for my language unary and binary at the same time I needed to add the following rules to my parser:

```
expr (MOD) expr                         #Modulo 
| op=(ADD|SUB) expr                     #UnaryPlusMinus
| expr op=(ADD|SUB) expr                #AddSub
| expr op=(AND|OR|XOR|NOT) expr         #LogOp
| NOT expr                              #NegOp
```

For me the above solution is fine because my language supports syntax like the following below:

- ++5---4   (result is 1)
- NOT NOT NOT 1  (result is 0)

However it would be interesting to create a parser/lexer rule where a operator (for example Minus) could be Unary or (Exclusive Or) Binary but the parser should know when the operator is used as Unary or Binary operator and therefore not allow something like this 5-++--4 , as this would lead to an error, but at the same time this would be ok ---5 as it would result to -5.